# Background image not on final result

Tags: rendering, image

Background image is not on the final result. These are my nodes:

[image]

And even though it is visible on the editor, when I render it the background is black and only the furniture is shown.

Comment: Is "Compositing" enabled in the "Post Processing" section? Do you have any strips on the VSE? Can you upload your file (with packed images)?

Comment: @cegaton yeah it's enabled. i could send you a zip file ?

Comment: No Zip files. **Pack** the images for the project (File>External Data> Pack All into . blend), upload the file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the resulting link as part of the text of your question.